# Creating sub folders using a path

Tags: excel, vba, directory, path, mkdir

Below is the code where I create subfolder A from the path on cell E3. This is the path: `C:\SW\A`. But what if I want to create these subfolders (A and B and C) using 1 path like `C:\SW\A\B\C`? This doesn't create the subfolders.

```
Sub MakeFolders()

 Dim path As String
'mkdir function
 path = Range("E3").Value 
MkDir path

End Sub
```

any idea how to make 3 subfolders using only 1 path?

Comment: You cannot. [**If path is a complex directory structure, the high-level directories must already exist or the MKDIR statement will raise an error.**](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mkdir.php) You will have to create them sequentially.

Comment: You could use the CreateFolder function I recently posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968510). Simply use the one-liner `CreateFolder "C:\SW\A\B\C"`.

Answer (score 0):

The Win32API, **MakeSureDirectoryExists**, will do what you're asking for - it will check if each folder in the path exists, and if not, it will make it. To use APIs, you need to make sure that Declaration component sits at the start of a module (along with its accompanying function, **BuildDirPath**)

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Lib "imagehlp.dll" (ByVal DirPath As String) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Lib "imagehlp.dll" (ByVal DirPath As String) As Long
#End If

Function BuildDirPath(ByVal Path As String) As Boolean
    BuildDirPath = CBool(MakeSureDirectoryPathExists(Path) = 1)
End Function
```

To use it, it's simply a matter of calling the function BuildDirPath.

```
Debug.Print BuildDirPath("C:\SW\A\B\C")
```

It will return a TRUE value if it was successful. I should add that this API is limited to ASCII characters and does not support Unicode - which means that it cannot be used for a non-Western character set (e.g., Japanese *hiragana*). Hope that helps.