# Create folders with cell values as names

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create folders if they don't currently exist for all cells in a worksheet. I already have the below code to check through the cells and add an appointment in Outlook if the conditions are met.

```
Sub test()

Dim OL As Outlook.Application, Appoint As Outlook.AppointmentItem, ES As Worksheet, _
R As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set ES = ActiveSheet
R = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set OL = New Outlook.Application

For i = 6 To R
With Cells(i, 1)
If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 6) = "" And Cells(i, 10) = "" Then
    Set Appoint = OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    With Appoint
        .Subject = ActiveSheet.Name & " - " & ES.Cells(i, 3).Value & " (" & ES.Cells(i, 4).Value & ")"
        .Start = ES.Cells(i, 9) + TimeValue("09:00:00")
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
        .body = "Create graphics for the following fixture -" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ES.Cells(i, 3).Value & " (" & ES.Cells(i, 4).Value & ")" & vbCrLf & ES.Cells(i, 1).Value & vbCrLf & ES.Cells(i, 2).Text & vbCrLf & ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
        .Save
        Cells(i, 10) = "Yes"
    End With
    End If
    End With
Next i
Set OL = Nothing

If Worksheets("Summary").Range("K1") = 0 Then MsgBox "All fixtures added."

End Sub
```

I'm looking to also create folders for each cell if they don't exist, with the path as below -

```
startPath = "W:\Gegenpress Graphics\"
teamName = ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Text
sponsorPath = "\Logos\Sponsors\"
```

but would also then need the created folder to be named `Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3)`

I'm just not sure how to go about it!

**EDIT FOLLOWING ANSWER FROM BLACK CAT**

I've tried amending the code to the below but getting "Next without For" - there is a For?

```
Sub CreateSponsorFoldersTest()

    Dim ES As Worksheet, _
    R As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = ActiveSheet
    R = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      
      
    Dim startPath As String
    Dim myName As String

    startPath = "W:\Gegenpress Graphics\"
    teamName = ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Text
    sponsorPath = "\Logos\Sponsors\"
    
       

    For i = 6 To R
    With Cells(i, 1)
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 6) = "" And Cells(i, 10) = "" Then
        Set myref = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
 On Error Resume Next
 myref.GetFolder (startPath & teamName & sponsorPath & Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3))
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Set m = myref.CreateFolder(startPath & teamName & sponsorPath & Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3))
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
    

If Worksheets("Summary").Range("K1") = 0 Then MsgBox "Sponsor Folders added."
```

Comment: While you added my code you delete lines from your own which made the complete program a mess. Pls. add the supplied code as insert.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The **Scripting.FileSystemObject** has a **CreateFolder** function whith which you can do this job.

This can be referenced with the Tools->References where select

Microsoft Scripting Runtime

C:\Windows\system32\scrrun.dll (in older Windows version)

An example in general

```
Set myref = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
[Set m =] myref.CreateFolder("c:\users\username\desktop\myfolder")
```

with your parameters

```
 Set myref = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
 On Error Resume Next
 myref.GetFolder (startpath & Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3))
 If Err <> 0 Then
 [Set m =] myref.CreateFolder(startpath & Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3))
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0
```

Pls. check this

```
For i = 6 To R
    'With Cells(i, 1)  not use it
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 6) = "" And Cells(i, 10) = "" Then
        Set myref = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
 On Error Resume Next
 myref.GetFolder (startPath & teamName & sponsorPath & Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3))
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Set m = myref.CreateFolder(startPath & teamName & sponsorPath & Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3))
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0
    End If        'inserted
    Next i
```

Comment: I've tried this, but got an error "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: @ffc2004 [Set m =] means that the use is optional. Either use, in this case delete brackets, or not than completely delete the text within the brackets and the brackets also.

Comment: @Blackcat I still see such a method of expression for the first time, I have more than ten years of experience and are not understand, not to mention the newcomer. Oh.

Comment: I've taken the brackets out now but now getting another error, I can't work it out!

Comment: @ffc2004 Did you make the reference?

Comment: I've posted the amended code in my original post

Comment: @ffc2004 Added to my answer the correction,  according to the missing end code of the Sub.

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to write and maintain code if the functionality os broken up into subroutines and functions that do specific jobs.

I used Folder and SubFodler for variables because no context was provided for:

> ```
> Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3)
> ```

Ideally, we would use more descriptive names.

```
Option Explicit

Rem Iterates over the Folders and Subfolder 
Rem Prints the Paths to the Immediate Window
Rem Creates the Paths if they don't exists

Sub CreateSponsorFolders()
    Const FirstRow As Long = 6
    Dim FolderName As Strin
    Dim SubFolderName As String
    Dim Path As String
    
    Dim r As Long, LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For r = FirstRow To LastRow
        FolderName = Cells(i, 36)
        SubFolderName = Cells(i, 3)
        Path = getSponsorFolder(FolderName, SubFolderName)
        CreateMissingFolders Path
        Debug.Print Path
    Next
    
End Sub

Rem Returns the Sponsor Folder and SubFolder Path 
Function getSponsorFolder(FolderName As String, SubFolderName As String) As String
    Const StartPath  As String = "W:\Gegenpress Graphics\"
    Const SponsorPath  As String = "\Logos\Sponsors\"
    Dim TeamName  As String
    
    ' Define the team name from the active sheet
    TeamName = ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Text
    
    ' Combine the parts of the path
    getSponsorFolder = StartPath & TeamName & SponsorPath & "\" & FolderName & "\" & SubFolderName
End Function

Rem Takes a directory path as an input (Path). It then breaks down this path into individual directory segments. The subroutine checks each segment of the directory structure, starting from the base and moving towards the end, to see if that directory exists. If it doesn't, the subroutine creates the directory. This ensures the complete path exists by the time the subroutine finishes.
Sub CreateMissingFolders(Path As String)
    Dim Folder As Variant
    Dim Folders As Variant
    Dim PathAccumulated As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Normalize the path string and split it into segments
    Path = Replace(Path, "\", "/")
    Folders = Split(Path, "/")

    ' Iterate over each segment and create directories as necessary
    For i = LBound(Folders) To UBound(Folders)
        PathAccumulated = PathAccumulated & Folders(i) & "\"
        ' Check if the directory exists
        If Dir(PathAccumulated, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            ' Directory doesn't exist, so create it
            MkDir PathAccumulated
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Create Folders

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateSponsorFoldersTEST()

    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 6
    Const START_PATH As String = "W:\Gegenpress Graphics\"
    Const SPONSOR_PATH As String = "\Logos\Sponsors\"

    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Long:
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then
        MsgBox "No data in worksheet.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim TeamName As String: TeamName = CStr(ws.Range("H3").Value)
    
    If Len(TeamName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No team name entered.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long, FolderPath As String
    
    For r = FIRST_ROW To LastRow
        If Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "A").Value)) > 0 _
                And Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "F").Value)) = 0 _
                And Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "J").Value)) = 0 Then
            FolderPath = START_PATH & TeamName & SPONSOR_PATH _
                & CStr(ws.Cells(r, "AJ").Value) & "\" _
                & CStr(ws.Cells(r, "C").Value)
            'Debug.Print FolderPath ' maybe test first to see if the paths are correct?
            CreateFolder FolderPath
        End If
    Next r
    
    If wb.Sheets("Summary").Range("K1") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sponsor Folders added.", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

**The Helper Method**

- You can find the code for the `CreateFolder` method at the bottom of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968510)

```vb
Sub CreateFolder(ByVal FolderPath As String)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The FileSystemObject (FSO) provides a built-in function called 'FolderExists' that can be used to check the existence of a folder. This approach eliminates the need for error handling.

```
Sub CreateSponsorFoldersTest()
    Dim ES As Worksheet, _
        R As Long, i As Long, WB As ThisWorkbook

    ' -- your code lines
       
    For i = 6 To R
        'With Cells(i, 1)   -- this line leads to compile error "next without for"
        If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 6) = "" And Cells(i, 10) = "" Then
            sFolder = startPath & teamName & sponsorPath & Cells(i, 36) & "\" & Cells(i, 3)
            Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
            If Not objFSO.FolderExists(sFolder) Then objFSO.CreateFolder folderPath
        End If
    Next i
    set objFSO = Nothing
    If Worksheets("Summary").Range("K1") = 0 Then MsgBox "Sponsor Folders added."
End Sub
```

By the way, if you need to manipulate the folder, you can obtain the folder object using the following lines of code.

```
If objFSO.FolderExists(sFolder) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
Else
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(folderPath)
End If
```